# React list already using unique keys but still getting unique key missing error in dev tools console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

React (Next.js) list already using unique keys but still getting unique key missing error in dev tools console.

Here's the `MenuListCategory` component render method:

```
render() {
    if (!this.props.listNames) return null;
    return (
        <Container>
            <Row
                className={'justify-content-start flex-nowrap menuCategory'}
                onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
                <Col xs={2} className={'flex-grow-0'}>
                    {
                        iconObject[
                            this.props.icon.slice(
                                this.props.icon.indexOf(':') + 1
                            )
                        ]
                    }
                </Col>
                <Col xs={10} className={'flex-grow-0'}>
                    <div className={'menuListName'}>{this.props.title}</div>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row
                className={`d-flex ${
                    this.state.subMenuStatus || this.props.subMenuStatus
                        ? 'menuCatOpen'
                        : 'menuCatClose'
                } px-3 flex-column`}
            >
                {this.props.listNames.map((v) => (
                    <MenuListItem
                        key={v.name?.name}
                        closeM={this.props.closeM}
                        description={v.name?.description}
                        name={v.name}
                        uid={v.uid}
                        changeBoard={this.props.changeBoard}
                        changeDescriptionTitle={
                            this.props.changeDescriptionTitle
                        }
                        activeRoute={this.props.activeRoute}
                    />
                ))}
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

The component import:

```
<MenuListCategory
    key={v.id + ' ' + v.name}
    closeM={this.props.handleMenu}
    listNames={this.props.listNames[i]}
    icon={v.icon}
    title={v.name}
/>;
```

And here the API:

```
  {
    "menuList": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "CategoryXYZ",
            "icon": "places:XYZ",
        },

        ...

   }
```

Since `id` is unique, I expected it to work as a unique key but somehow it doesn't. Both `name` and `id` are already unique. I've tried using `key={v.id}` and `key={v.name}` though both give the same error in dev tools dev tools React component tab, found below, via the Chrome extension for React debugging. I also tried the even more unique `key={v.id + ' ' + v.name}` but get the same result.

Am getting this warning in React dev tools:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check
> the render method of `MenuListCategory` ...

I'm trying to avoid installing a package to manage the unique id.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Surely, it's been encountered before, I'm just not able to find anything regarding *already* having unique id which aren't being recognised as unique.

Comment: "*Check the render method of MenuListCategory*". Show us the render method.

Comment: @morganney Thanks, I've added the full render method.

Comment: The error message is referring to the render method of the `MenuListCategory` component, not the Container. Show us that render method, or look there which is probably why you are confused.

Comment: @morganney Thanks, I've also added the render method of the `MenuListCategory` component.

Comment: This `key={v.name?.name}` implies that `name` can be nullish and thus `key` will be `undefined`, possibly for more than one `MenuListItem`.

Comment: Try `key={v.name?.name ?? idx}` where `idx` is the index param from the associated `map`.

Comment: @morganney Excellent, this did the trick. Thank you! I've some reading to do regarding Nullish coalescing operator (??).